# protobuf-maven-plugin, jenkins build fail

Tags: maven, jenkins, protocol-buffers

I am new for Jenkins building jobs.

Currently, i am trying to build a project which has protobuf-maven-plugin init for compile .proto file to generate required java file from it.

In local machine, able to do maven install build from STS by specifying protoc.exe path in Path environment variables. Where as in Jenkins it is failing to locate protoc, by stating below error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.igor-petruk.protobuf:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.5:run (default) on project betstream-proto: 
Cannot execute 'protoc': Cannot run program "protoc": error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
```

Where as Jenkins is already deployed in Dev environment of my company.

Please any one help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to get whomever runs your jenkins server to install protoc on it.